# jQuery mobile open popup from popup

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, popup

I'm using jQuery mobile `1.9.1 min` on PhoneGap.
I have a list where each iten on click opens an actions popup:

```js
function showActions(index){
    selectedIndex = index; 
    $("#actionPopup").popup("open", {positionTo: '#list li:nth-child('+ index +')'});
}
```

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="actionPopup" data-overlay-theme="a">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="divider">Actions</li>
                <li data-icon="false" onclick="showDetails();">action1</li>
                <li data-icon="false">action2</li>
                <li data-icon="false">action3</li>
                <li data-icon="false">action4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

When I press on action1 with `showDetails()` them method is called but the second popup isn't shown.

```js
function showDetails(){
    console.log("showDetails");
    $("#infoPopup").popup("open");
}
```

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="infoPopup">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
            <div id="infoContent">
                <table>
                    <tr id="eventcode">
                        <td>test1:</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="eventtype">
                        <td>test2:</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution

```
$.mobile.switchPopup = function(sourceElement, destinationElement, onswitched) {
    var afterClose = function() {
        destinationElement.popup("open");
        sourceElement.off("popupafterclose", afterClose);

        if (onswitched && typeof onswitched === "function"){
            onswitched();
        }
    };

    sourceElement.on("popupafterclose", afterClose);
    sourceElement.popup("close");
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I used this simple function for the work-around:

```
function myPopup(myPage) {
    history.back();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(myPage).popup('open');
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Rakoo has a nice answer. Here is a leaner version:

```
$.mobile.switchPopup = function(sourceElement, destinationElement, onswitched) {
    sourceElement.one("popupafterclose", function() {
        destinationElement.popup("open")
        !onswitched || typeof onswitched !== "function" || onswitched()
    }).popup("close")
};
```

If you don't need the onswitched feature and aren't adding it to $.mobile, It can be this short and simple:

```
$('#popup1').one("popupafterclose", function(){$('#popup2').popup("open")}).popup("close")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that chaining popups is not [possible](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/).

The solution:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", function() {
    $( '.popupParent' ).on({
        popupafterclose: function() {
            setTimeout( function(){ $( '.popupChild' ).popup( 'open' ) }, 100 );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to switch popup from popup it works fine.

```
function switchpop()
{
    $( '#popupMenu' ).popup( 'close' );  
    $( "#popupMenu" ).bind({popupafterclose: function(event, ui) 
            { 
                $( "#notes" ).popup( "open" );
            }
            });                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After four hours of fighting with this I reduced the problem to this:

This is in a button click function on the first popup

```
    $('#popupCall').popup('close');

    window.setTimeout(function () { $('#popupContact').popup('open') }, 50);
```