# jQuery Mobile popup does not open after closing previous popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery popup that takes in user input which can lead to errors.  I want to have a 2nd popup come up if there are errors, but I cannot get this working.

Here is a boiled down example, which I also have in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tz4ju/2/

The HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="popup" id="errorDialog" class='ui-corner-none ui-content'>
        <p id="errormsg"></p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="popup" id="addFolderDialog" class='ui-corner-none portalpopup'>
        <div data-role='content'>
            <p></p>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="name">New Folder:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="newfolder_val" value="" class="ret_submit" rel="adddir_submit" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" id="adddir_submit" onclick='create_folder_submit()'>Add Folder</a>
                <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel='back'>Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p><a href="#addFolderDialog" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a></p>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
window.create_folder_submit = function () {
    $("#addFolderDialog").popup("close");
    $("#errormsg").text("ERROR!");
    $("#errorDialog").popup("open");
}
```

By the way, if I call `$("#errorDialog").popup("open")` anywhere else, it works.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know jquery the best but have you tried anything with a CSS z-index to make sure it will display on top and not behind the current overlay?

Comment: I checked the z-index and that is ok.  Also, I should clarify that I am closing the previous overlay, then opening the new one, so only 1 overlay should be visible at any point in time.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/tz4ju/17/

Comment: Cool, that works.  I can't figure out why though.  Also strange, when I set the setTimeout to 0 it works, but if I remove setTimeout and try to open the error dialog directly, it breaks.  Either way it works.

Comment: @Aravinth if you add that an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: @CharlesL. i answered....see it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Documentation (see at the page end)](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/) Chaining popups are not allowed in jquery mobile.

You can achive the chaining popup like the following.

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", function() {
$( '.popupParent' ).on({
    popupafterclose: function() {
        setTimeout( function(){ $( '.popupChild' ).popup( 'open' ) }, 100 );
    }
});
});
```

Refer this **<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/tz4ju/17/)</kbd>**

Comment: Is this still the same issue?
I am using the delay strategy, but even with 350 it seems to give problems now and then on slower devices.
Do we still not have a solid way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser pop-up blocker. So setinterval needs to be used to trigger it.

Simply write your js like this,

```
window.create_folder_submit = function () {
    $("#addFolderDialog").popup("close");
    $("#errormsg").text("ERROR!");
    var popup = setInterval(function(){
        $("#errorDialog").popup('open');
        clearInterval(popup);
    },1);
};
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS WORKING FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/D93UF/)**</kbd>

Comment: This does not work on my machine.  When I increase the delay it does, but this seems like a big hack.   It inspired me to try $( "#addFolderDialog" ).bind({
        popupafterclose: function(event, ui) {
            console.log('close add')
            $("#errormsg").text("ERROR!");
            $("#errorDialog").popup('open');
        }
    }); without success.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using popupafterclose event can't work since it will be fired every time you will leave the popup. even if you click on "cancel". 
You should make a simple delay between the closing and the opening.